# GWT Fetch Image before Use

Tags: gwt, image-loading, image-load

In a GWT application, i'm sure to use one image, but i want the application to load only when the image i'm going to use has already been loaded so that the user does not see the image partially loading, how can i do it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like [`Image.prefetch(String url)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html#prefetch%28java.lang.String%29)?